# How do I get /usr/bin/python3 back after deleting it?

Tags: 18.04, apt, python3

I downloaded Chromedriver and moved it into `/usr/bin/python3`, and it kept running and failing in my terminal, and I couldn't work out how to remove it from python3, which my file manager said was a shared library.

So I performed a `rm -f` on `/usr/bin/python3` and well, it got rid of chromedriver. But now I can't start applications such as lollypop and catfish.

Now, when I try to run them, an error occurs:

```
bash: /usr/bin/lollypop: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out how to reinstall python3. I've tried:

```
sudo aptitude install python3
sudo apt-get install python3-all
```

but nothing seems to work. Have I broken my install?
I am on Ubuntu 18.04, running XFCE.

This is the output of `ls /usr/bin/python3*`:

[image]

Comment: here is the output: https://imgur.com/0wFiCG9

Comment: it works!! thankyou :)) is this because python 3.6 is backward compatible with python3, and you made a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't delete the Python 3 which Ubuntu was using, instead you deleted only the symbolic link. `/usr/bin/python3` is the symlink which points to the default Python 3 version being used in Ubuntu. You can check the default version of Python 3 by doing a [package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). In 18.04, 3.6 is the default version. Luckily, it wasn't deleted. To recreate the symlink, you can simply use [`ln`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ln.1posix.html), i.e.,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: so if i had deleted usr/bin/python3.6, i would have been in a lot more trouble?

Comment: @IvanLendl Absolutely.